# Gridview dynamic update w/ SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a SqlDataSource that updates whenever a user specifies a value. I'm trying to do the following to update the gridview as well, but the gridview won't show anything. Did I miss anything here?

```
private void updateSessionGridView(string p)
{
    session.SelectCommand = @"SELECT TOP 10  * FROM [MyDB]
                                    where key = '" + p + "'";
    GridView1.DataSourceID = null; 
    GridView1.DataSource = session;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Is this for ASP.Net or WinForms?

Comment: for ASP.net. I enabled the AutoGenerateSelectButton. Only 10 "Select" column is shown but no actual data.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a data source control, then you need to set the DataSourceID property, not the DataSource property.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either when I change the code to GridView1.DataSource = session.ID

Comment: No, do not set `DataSource`. See `DataSourceID'.

Comment: I've edited the answer. If you want to remove the downvote, you should be able now.